# I tried to wrote verilog code of 4-bit register with parallel load. But i failed. I am pasting code with output.Please identify whats wrong with it

Tags: verilog

The circuit is :

[image]

The verilog code I wrote :

```
module four_bit_register(out,in,load,cp,clear);
  output [3:0] out;
  input [3:0] in;
  input load,cp,clear;
  //Instantiate sr_flip flop with other input circuit.

  sr_ff sr0(out[0],in[0],load,cp,clear);
  sr_ff sr1(out[1],in[1],load,cp,clear);                           
  sr_ff sr2(out[2],in[2],load,cp,clear);
  sr_ff sr3(out[3],in[3],load,cp,clear);
endmodule

module sr_ff(out,in,load,cp,clear);
  //Input output port declaration.
  output out;
  input in,load,cp,clear;
  //internal wire declaration.
  wire s,r,sin,rin;
  wire qbar;

  assign s= load & in,
         r= load & (~in);
  // sr_flip flop.
  assign sin=s&clear&(cp),
         rin=r&clear&(cp);
  assign out=~(rin|qbar),
         qbar=~(sin|out);
endmodule                                       

module stimulus;
  reg [3:0] in;
  reg load,cp,clear;
  wire [3:0] out;

  four_bit_register register (out,in,load,cp,clear);

  initial begin
    #5 in=4'b1101;
    load=1'b1;
    clear=1'b1;
    cp=1'b0;
  end

  initial
    forever begin
      #50 cp=~cp;
    end

  initial
    #700 $finish;

endmodule
```

The verilog output:

[image]

I am getting a high impedance on all input output. I checked it many time but not able to run it correctly . Please help anyone.

*Note .. I am using Xilinx ISE 10.1

Comment: Use non-blocking assignment <= when assigning to reg data type. So in module stimulus (test bench for your module sr_ff), "forever begin #50 cp <= ~cp; end". See if that gets the clock running in behavioral simulation.

After you get cp clock running, if you find s and r get assigned the same value, try "assign s = (expr1); assign r = (expr2);" instead of "assign s = (expr1), r = (expr2);". Sutherland HDL Verilog 2001 Reference Guide doesn't show comma as valid operator, nor assign for multiple expressions.

Comment: @MarkU clock generators are the exception to the rule and normally us blocking assignment. The comma in the `assign` statement is legal syntax (just uncommon), see IEEE 1364-1995 section A.6  or IEEE 1364-2001 section A.6.1

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you accidentally simulated the four-bit register itself instead of the testbench, so it's as if there was no stimulus and the register output remains undefined (but *not* high impedance, as you said).

Another problem could be a missing `timespec`.

Please format your code properly if you expect more detailed help.

Comment: format? can you give me hint which kind of formatting?

Comment: Another user was kind enough to change your pasted text into a proper markdown code block, but you need to indent the code to show structure.